# Why is Outlook stripping the colour of my email buttons?

Tags: html, email

I'm trying to amend an email template to show different colour buttons. It will happily display them as white, which is fine. But on changing the colour to anything else (red, green, blue whatever) the moment I change them outlook strips them back to white.

This is really frustrating, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="backgroundTable" style="">
  <!-- Columns Image With button -->
  <!-- Wrapper -->
  <table class="w100pc" data-component="wrapper" role="presentation" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:600px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="w100pc" data-component="wrapper" width="600" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:24px;padding-left:0px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;width:600px;">
          <!-- Row -->
          <table class="w100pc" data-component="row" role="presentation" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:600px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="w100pc" data-component="row" width="600" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;width:600px;">
                  <table class="w100pc" data-component="row" role="presentation" width="600" dir="ltr" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:600px;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <!-- Spacer-->
                        <th class="w10pc" data-component="spacer" width="24" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:24px;"></th>
                        <!-- Column -->
                        <th class="w100pc full" data-component="column" width="222" dir="ltr" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFD300" style="padding-top:24px;padding-right:24px;padding-bottom:24px;padding-left:24px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;width:222px;">
                          <table class="w100pc" data-component="column" role="presentation" width="176" align="center" bgcolor="#FFD300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:176px;">
                            <tbody>
                              <!-- Title-->
                              <tr>
                                <td class="customFont w100pc aH--c" data-component="text" width="222" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFD300" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:12px;padding-left:0px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;font-family:'Poppins', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-text-raise:1.25;line-height:18px;color:#101820;width:222px;">
                                  <h2 style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;font-size:25px;line-height:29px">XXXX </h2>
                                  <h2>
                                  </h2>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <!-- Button-->
                              <tr>
                                <td class="w100pc" data-component="button" width="222" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFD300" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;width:222px;">
                                  <table class="w100pc" data-component="button" role="button" align="center" bgcolor="#FFD300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="222" style="width:222px;border-collapse:separate !important;">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="customFont" data-component="button" align="center">
                                          <div>
                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                                                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.blank.com" fillcolor="#ffffff" arcsize="125%" stroke="f" style="width:222px;height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;">
                                                                  <w:anchorlock/>
                                                                  <center class="customFont" style="font-family:'poppins',Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;color:#101820;">SHOP NOW</center>
                                                                </v:roundrect><![endif]-->
                                            <a href="https://www.blank.com" target="_blank" style="background-color:#3BAA34;border:0;border-radius:50px;display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;width:222px;mso-hide:all;border-radius:50px;"><span style="color:#101820;font-family:'poppins',Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-weight:600;line-height:40px;">SHOP NOW</span></a>
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <!-- Spacer-->
                        <th class="h-24 w100pc full" data-component="spacer" width="12" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:12px;"></th>
                        <!-- Column -->
                        <th class="w100pc full" data-component="column" width="222" dir="ltr" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFD300" style="padding-top:24px;padding-right:24px;padding-bottom:24px;padding-left:24px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;width:222px;">
                          <table class="w100pc" data-component="column" role="presentation" width="176" align="center" bgcolor="#FFD300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:176px;">
                            <tbody>
                              <!-- Title-->
                              <tr>
                                <td class="customFont w100pc aH--c" data-component="text" width="222" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFD300" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;font-family:'Poppins', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;mso-text-raise:1.25;line-height:18px;color:#101820;width:222px;">
                                  <h2 style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:12px;font-size:25px;line-height:29px">XXXXX
                                  </h2>
                                  <h2>
                                  </h2>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <!-- Button-->
                              <tr>
                                <td class="w100pc" data-component="button" width="222" align="center" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFD300" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0;width:222px;">
                                  <table class="w100pc" data-component="button" role="button" align="center" bgcolor="#FFD300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="222" style="width:222px;border-collapse:separate !important;">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="customFont" data-component="button" align="center">
                                          <div>
                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                                                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.blank.com" fillcolor="#ffffff" arcsize="125%" stroke="f" style="width:222px;height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;">
                                                                  <w:anchorlock/>
                                                                  <center class="customFont" style="font-family:'poppins',Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;color:#101820;">SHOP NOW</center>
                                                                </v:roundrect><![endif]-->
                                            <a href="https://www.blank.com" target="_blank" style="background-color:#3BAA34;border:0;border-radius:50px;display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;width:222px;mso-hide:all;border-radius:50px;"><span style="color:#101820;font-family:'poppins',Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-weight:600;line-height:40px;">SHOP NOW</span></a>
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <!-- Spacer-->
                        <th class="w10pc" data-component="spacer" width="24" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:24px;"></th>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using normal CSS instead of HTML attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses VML buttons. (That might come from a generator like [buttons.cm](https://buttons.cm).) So your typical button code looks like this:

```html
<!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://www.blank.com" fillcolor="#ffffff" arcsize="125%" stroke="f" style="width:222px;height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;">
  <w:anchorlock/>
  <center class="customFont" style="font-family:'poppins',Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;color:#101820;">
    SHOP NOW
  </center>
</v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
<a href="https://www.blank.com" target="_blank" style="background-color:#3BAA34;border:0;border-radius:50px;display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;width:222px;mso-hide:all;border-radius:50px;">
  <span style="color:#101820;font-family:'poppins',Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font-weight:600;line-height:40px;">
    SHOP NOW
  </span>
</a>
```

You changed the `background-color` in the HTML part, but not in the VML part. In order to get a green button here, you need to change the `fillcolor="#ffffff"` attribute of the `<v:roundrect>` element.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. What if I wanted the 2 buttons to be different colours? How would I affect that change?

I may have just looked and been able to answer my own question. The colour in the VML is specific to each button, rather than "buttons" over the entire email.